# How to Restore RDS TDE enabled backup into another RDS SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, aws, transparent-data-encryption

I enabled TDE encryption on RDS SQL SERVER with default RDS CERTIFICATE.
I took native backup of same RDS on S3 bucket and want to restore same backup file into another RDS SQL SERVER.

Source - RDS TDE ENABLED.

Destination - RDS without TDE Encryption.

RDS - SQL SERVER 2019 Enterprise.